# Handling Error message in output of Representation

Tags: r, knitr

I get error messages in R presentation tool which I want to skip.

I used

```
{ r echo = FALSE, error = TRUE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE }
```

at top of my chunk of codes but they still populate my HTML output. How can I get rid of these error messages?

By the way, the errors come from trying to read empty CSV files. I would be happy to get rid of/skip these errors all together (in R console or in HTML output).